# How to sort ordered pairs by one coordinate with the other serving as tie-breaker

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a collection of $N$ ordered pairs,

$$\{\{x_{1},y_{1}\},\cdots,\{x_{N},y_{N}\}\}$$

These ordered pairs can have at most one entry in common, i.e., if $x_{i}=x_{j} \left(y_{i}=y_{j}\right)$ for some $i$ and $j$, then $y_{i}\neq y_{j} \left(x_{i}\neq x_{j}\right)$. I want to sort this list of ordered pairs from smallest $x$ value to largest, and in the case where several $x$ values are equal, I want to arrange that portion of the list from smallest $y$ value to largest. I can accomplish the first step by writing

```
Sort[,#1[[1]]<#2[[1]] &]
```

But as far as I can tell this doesn't guarantee that the list will be sorted by $y$-value when the $x$ values agree. What can I do to make it so?

Comment: If you have numbers, just use single-argument Sort.

Comment: I was actually aware of this, but this list is actually embedded in a larger list in such a way that I want to use the more complicated approach.

Comment: Can you provide an example of why a complicated function is needed rather than the trivial `Sort`?

Comment: @mflynn Then use `SortBy` with a function that extracts the pair from the larger list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {30, 2}];

Flatten[Sort[ #, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &      ] & /@ 
  SplitBy[Sort[data, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &], First], 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

### SortBy or Ordering

> SortBy[*list*, $\it{\{f_1, f_2, \ldots\}}$] *breaks ties by successively using the values obtained from the $f_i$.* [***](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SortBy.html)

```
data = RandomInteger[5, {10, 5}];
sorted = SortBy[data, {First, Last}];
ordered = data[[Ordering[data[[All, {1, -1}]]]]];

sorted == ordered
```

> True

```
Grid[Transpose[{data, sorted, ordered}], Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \{5,5,5,1,4\} & \{0,2,2,2,0\} & \{0,2,2,2,0\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,0,5,3,2\} & \{1,0,5,3,2\} & \{1,0,5,3,2\} \\
> \hline
>  \{4,0,4,4,2\} & \{1,1,0,5,4\} & \{1,1,0,5,4\} \\
> \hline
>  \{2,2,4,5,5\} & \{1,1,4,0,5\} & \{1,1,4,0,5\} \\
> \hline
>  \{3,3,0,0,1\} & \{2,2,4,5,5\} & \{2,2,4,5,5\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1,0,5,4\} & \{3,3,0,0,1\} & \{3,3,0,0,1\} \\
> \hline
>  \{0,2,2,2,0\} & \{3,4,0,2,3\} & \{3,4,0,2,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \{3,4,0,2,3\} & \{4,0,4,4,2\} & \{4,0,4,4,2\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1,4,0,5\} & \{4,4,1,2,5\} & \{4,4,1,2,5\} \\
> \hline
>  \{4,4,1,2,5\} & \{5,5,5,1,4\} & \{5,5,5,1,4\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$